# Command Line C++ Program to Send an EMail

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, email

I'm using VS2008 & C++ and I'm trying to create a command line program that sends an email.
I've looked on line and found some sample programs but none will compile for me.
Does anyone have an example program for me?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of email are you trying to send?  IMAP? native Exchange? POP3?

Comment: I'm trying to send a simple text message in the bodyof the email, I dont want to send attachements or anything like that.  I'm on a LAN with an exchange e-mail server so I would be using it to send the e-mail.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: There are no "kinds" of email. Email is almost always sent via SMTP. The protocols you listed are ways to *receive* email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code compiles & runs for me - after figuring out the right headers etc. Still needs command line handling, and the use of the MAPI libraries is deprecated, but what do you want for free? Original code from codeproject.com

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "tchar.h"

#include "mapi.h"
#include "assert.h"
#define ASSERT assert
#define VERIFY assert

BOOL SendMail(CHAR *lpszFrom, CHAR *lpszTo, CHAR *lpszSubject, CHAR *lpszMessage)
{
   BOOL bSent = FALSE;

   HINSTANCE hMAPI = ::LoadLibrary(_T("mapi32.dll"));
   if(0==hMAPI) return bSent;

   typedef ULONG (FAR PASCAL *PFN_MAPILogon)(ULONG,LPTSTR,LPTSTR,FLAGS,ULONG,LPLHANDLE);
   typedef ULONG (FAR PASCAL *PFN_MAPISendMail)(LHANDLE,ULONG,lpMapiMessage,FLAGS,ULONG);
   typedef ULONG (FAR PASCAL *PFN_MAPILogoff)(LHANDLE,ULONG,FLAGS,ULONG);

   PFN_MAPILogon MAPILogon = (PFN_MAPILogon)::GetProcAddress(hMAPI,"MAPILogon");
   PFN_MAPISendMail MAPISendMail = (PFN_MAPISendMail)::GetProcAddress(hMAPI,"MAPISendMail");
   PFN_MAPILogoff MAPILogoff = (PFN_MAPILogoff)::GetProcAddress(hMAPI,"MAPILogoff");

   const BOOL bFunctionsLoaded = (0!=MAPILogon)&&(0!=MAPISendMail)&&(0!=MAPILogoff);
   ASSERT(bFunctionsLoaded);

   if(bFunctionsLoaded)
   {

      LHANDLE session = 0;
      VERIFY(SUCCESS_SUCCESS==MAPILogon(0,0,0,MAPI_NEW_SESSION,0,&session));
      ASSERT(0!=session);

      MapiRecipDesc recipient;
      ::ZeroMemory(&recipient,sizeof(recipient));
      recipient.ulRecipClass = MAPI_TO;
      recipient.lpszName = lpszTo;

      MapiMessage message;
      ::ZeroMemory(&message,sizeof(message));
      message.lpszSubject = lpszSubject;
      message.lpszNoteText = lpszMessage;
      message.nRecipCount = 1;
      message.lpRecips = &recipient;

      bSent = SUCCESS_SUCCESS == MAPISendMail(session,0,&message,0,0);

      VERIFY(SUCCESS_SUCCESS==MAPILogoff(session,0,0,0));

   }

   ::FreeLibrary(hMAPI);

   return bSent;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   SendMail("from_you@go_daddy.com","to.someone@gmail.com","Test subject","New Message");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked! however it does caue outlook to prompt me to allow the program to send the e-mail.  I got around this by installing Click Yes http://www.contextmagic.com/express-clickyes/  Since my program will run on an internal PC it's not a problem to install this software.

Comment: Yes - that's because this is using the MAPI server to send the mail on the PC. There are alternative solutions that don't use MAPI, so you can look into that later -

Comment: @Jeff do you know why I get "assert is not defined" in line ASSERT(bFunctionsLoaded); ?
thank you

Comment: It's probably related to the "assert.h" you included. Assert() is just a convenient error checking macro to test if something is true, so you can substitute other code, or remove it altogether for test.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/blat/files/

Comment: thanks for the link, but I was kinda hoping for a simple command line program that I could easily understand so I could use the same logic in my program.

Answer (score 1):

Since your server is Exchange, your most convenient method to write a program to send email will be using C# and [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) as demonstrated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx).  Here is the C++/CLI code:

```
   static void CreateTestMessage2( String^ server )
   {
      String^ to = L"jane@contoso.com";
      String^ from = L"ben@contoso.com";
      MailMessage^ message = gcnew MailMessage( from,to );
      message->Subject = L"Using the new SMTP client.";
      message->Body = L"Using this new feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
      SmtpClient^ client = gcnew SmtpClient( server );

      // Credentials are necessary if the server requires the client 
      // to authenticate before it will send e-mail on the client's behalf.
      client->UseDefaultCredentials = true;
      client->Send( message );
      client->~SmtpClient();
   }
```

If you really want to use native C++ (ie. not access System.Net.Mail via C++/CLI) then you are stuck with one of the native APIs described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200018).

However you could use MapiSend or [blat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blat/) as described [here](http://www.msexchange.org/articles/Sending-Email-without-Client.html).

Comment: I agree c# would be a lot easier, however I need to intergrate sending an e-mail with an existing C++ command line program.