# sending e-mail from c++ code

Tags: c++, email, visual-c++

I am making a console app that needs to send e-mail when asked so.How could i do that ?
Though i tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872342/command-line-c-program-to-send-an-email) it was not successful, because you need additional software for it. **AND** there is a delay of about 10 minutes when i actually get the email.what could be the problem ?

*This is the dialog box displayed when you run the first code*

[image]

Is there any other way out ?

Are there any links that explain sending e-mail from c++ program step by step explaining the function used in the code.

Comment: What's wrong with that dialog? It's a security feature, designed to protect the user's privacy and email accounts. It clearly explains the situation, and gives them the opportunity to cancel if they want to. If not, it goes ahead and sends the email. This is exactly what you want. Don't try and fix problems that are not broken.

Comment: @ Cody Gray there is a delay of about 10 minutes when i get the e-mail using that code ?  What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: Does the progress bar last 10 minutes? Otherwise, I assume that the problem has more to do with your email account.

Comment: @ Cody Gray no. It takes minimal time. What do you mean by **"problem has more to do with your email account."**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give [VMime](http://www.vmime.org/) a try!

(Sending mail is not a language built-in feature, you will have to use some sort of library.)

Comment: Search for vmime.NET on Codeproject.com! (SMTP, POP3 and IMAP library for C++ and .NET programmers with SSL and TLS support)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to open a mail window in your default mail agent, use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

```
ShellExecute(
  NULL,
  NULL,
  TEXT("mailto:foo@example.com"),
  NULL,
  NULL,
  SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Additionally: [connected topic: *C++ SMTP Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210/c-smtp-example).

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: Check it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=VS.85%29.aspx): _Shellapi.h_.

Comment: Doesn't this just open a mail window in your default mail agent?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: yes, sorry.

Comment: The OP is looking for a solution that doesn't require third-party software. (Since C++ has no mail functionality, he's going to _need_ third-party software, but he can use a library rather than something completely external to the resultant application.)

Answer (score 2):

For sending eMail you can open a tcp network socket to the mailserver of the recipient, e.g. smtpmail.example.com, port 25.

For details to Windows sockets programming see http://www.snible.org/winsock/ or other tutorials.

Then write text to that socket according to the SMTP protocol:

```
HELO mymachine_ipaddress_or_dnsname
MAIL FROM:<me@somewhere.net>
DATA

From: <me@somewhere.net>
To: <you@example.com>
Subject: Test message

Hello, greetings.
.
QUIT
```

Then close socket. In fact, there is no built-in sender authentication in SMTP...

Answer (score 1):

[libCurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is a highly portable C/C++ networking library that supports SMTP. There is [a sample](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplesmtp.html) on their site.

Comment: Wow, sweet. I never knew that, very handy.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CDO for doing this. I think it bypases the outlook object model. So you wont get this warning dialogue also.